# comparing strings and determining if they are identical with hidden values

Tags: python, string

So lets say you are given two strings, with hidden values and you want to know if there is a possibility of them being the same, so for example you have the word 'jupiter', now lets say '^' represents hidden values, for example:
   'jupiter' could equal = 'j^^^t^r , but not 'j^^^' becuase thats only 4 characters, or '^a^^^^' because the second character isint a in 'jupiter'. I have no idea how to start the program, thanks again guys!

also, new to python, thanks guys!

Comment: What have you tried? This is quite simple logically and would take only a few minutes to do out on paper before trying to tackle it straight in code.

Comment: Your 'hidden values' string is basically a regex with '^' instead of '.'.

Answer (score 3):

I'd do it like this:

1. Make sure the two strings have the same length. If they don't, they cannot be the same word.
2. Iterate over one string and keep a counter variable. You can use `for index, letter in enumerate(word):` to simplify this.
3. Compare `letter` to the letter in the same position from `word2` (you can use `word2[index]`).
4. If `letter` isn't a `^` and the two letters from the words differ, `return False`, because the two words cannot be the same.
5. Once the loop ends, if you haven't returned already, `return True`.

Here's a cryptic one-liner, just for reference:

```
len(w1) == len(w2) and all(a == b or '^' in a + b for a, b in zip(w1, w2))
```

Or with regex:

```
re.match('^{}$'.format(w2.replace('^', '.')), w1)
```

Comment: `all(...)` variant doesn't check condition `1`.

Comment: The '^' is redundant for re.match

Answer (score 0):

```
def match(st,t):
 if len(st)!=len(t):
  return False
 for i,j in zip(t,st):
   if i!="^" and i!=j:
    return False
 return True

>>> st="jupiter"
>>> t="j^p^^e^"
>>> match(st,t)
True
>>> t="j^"
>>> match(st,t)
False
>>> t="j^pit^e"
>>>
>>> match(st,t)
False
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> def compare(A,B):
...     if not len(A) == len(B): return False
...     return all(a == b or a == '^' or b == '^' for a,b in zip(A,B))
... 
>>> compare('j^^^t^r','jupiter')
True
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
def match(a,b):
    if len(a)!=len(b):
        return "strings don't match"
    else:
        for x,y in zip(a,b):
            if not(any((x=="^",y=="^")) or x==y):
                return "strings don't match"
        return "matched"

print match("jupiter","j^^^t^r")    
print match("jupiter","^a^^^^^")
print match("abc","^b^")
print match("abc","b^^")
```

**output:**

```
matched
strings don't match
matched
strings don't match
```